# From controller, data is not transforming to html view page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying send the data through controller to html page but unable data transmission is getting failed. Control is redirecting to the desired page along with labels but form data is not reflecting in the view page.

> ```
>    ***HomeController***
> ```

```
 package com.example.demo.web;      

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

    import com.example.demo.domain.User;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        User user = new User();

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home(Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("formData", user);

            return "index";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String processFormData(User user, RedirectAttributes attr) {

            attr.addFlashAttribute("user",user);
            return "redirect:display";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/display", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String displayFormData(User user) {
            return "result";
        }

    }
```

> ***index.html***

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">

    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title> Home Page </title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <p> Enter Data Below </p>
    <form action="/create" method="post" th:object="${formData}">

    <p>Full Name:<input type="text" th:feild="${formData.fullName}"/></p>
    <p>Age:<input type="text" th:feild="${formData.age}"/></p>
    <p>Employed?<input type="checkbox" th:feild="${formData.employed}" th:value="true"/></p>
    <p>Gender:</p>
    <p>Male<input type="radio" th:feild="${formData.gender}" th:value="Male"/>
       Female<input type="radio" th:feild="${formData.gender}" th:value="Female"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

> ***result.html***

```
<html xmlns:th="https://thymeleaf.org">  
<table>  
<tr>  
<td><h4>User Name: </h4></td>  
<td><h4 th:text="${user.fullName}"></h4></td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td><h4>Age: </h4></td>  
<td><h4 th:text="${user.age}"></h4></td>  
</tr>  
</table>  
</html>
```

Comment: can you post, what is the error you are getting or at which step are you stuck??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller class sends and reads a form view. The User data is passed as a parameter to the processForm() handler. Spring tries to fill the bean with the request data. The data is also automatically available for the Thymeleaf result view. The @Controller annotation allows the implementation classes to be autodetected through the classpath scanning.

`@Controller` is typically used in combination with a @RequestMapping annotation used on request handling methods. I used the `@GetMapping` and @@PostMapping` as a shortcut to `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`

```
@Controller 
public class HomeController {
//This responds to localhost:8080/
@GetMapping("/")
    public String sendForm(User user){
    return "index";
}

//This responds to localhost:8080/
@PostMapping("/")
    public String processForm(User user){
    return "result";
}
```

User Class.  This is the User class. It is automatically filled with data from the form request. The attributes must match the form fields. You should be able to see the matching attribute names in the template views below.

```
    public class User {

        private String fullName;
        private int age;
        private String occupation;

        public String getFullName() {
            return fullName;
        }

        public void setFullName(String name) {
            this.fullName = name;
        }

        public String getOccupation() {
            return occupation;
        }

        public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
            this.occupation = occupation;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
```

index.html
The `th:object` refers to the user form bean. This is not a class name, but a Spring bean name; therefore it is in lowercase.  With the *{} syntax, we refer to the defined object. In this case its the `user` object. I noticed that you misspelled `th:field`, this can also create bugs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p> Enter Data Below </p>
<form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

    <p>Full Name:<input type="text" th:field="*{fullName}" id="fullName" name="fullname" autofocus="autofocus"></p>
    <p>Age:<input type="number" th:field="*{age}" id="age" name="age" autofocus="autofocus" /></p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

result.html
We identify the form attributes with the ${} syntax.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>User Name: </h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${user.fullName}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h4>Age: </h4></td>
        <td><h4 th:text="${user.age}"></h4></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Abby Howe. Now i clearly understand the concept nad flow. Thanks again

Comment: @Narendra Please mark this answer as correct if your issue is resolved. Thanks